# Example of nondecreasing, convex and smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

Given a real constant $C$ (nonnegative), what is an example of a real-valued increasing function $f$ defined on the real line that is both smooth and convex, and that $f$ vanishes at points $x$ iff $x$ $\leq$ $C$ ?

Thank you so much for any suggestion.

Comment: I would take $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: @gerw this won't work for the obvious reason. Remember we want $f > 0$ when $x>C$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed the second 'f' in 'iff'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an infinitely differentiable example, use $\exp(-1/(x-C))$ for $x>C$.

Edit: As orangeskid pointed out in a comment, this function $f$ isn't convex, but $\int_C^xf(t)\,dt$ is convex and retains the other desired properties.

Comment: integrate once based at C to get convexity

Comment: @orangeskid Thanks for the correction; I've edited the answer to incorporate it.

Comment: @Andreas Blass how is this well-defined ?

Comment: @S_j $f$  is well-defined because I gave an explicit formula for it.  The definite integral of $f$ is well-defined because $f$ is continuous and therefore integrable.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Oh sorry, I was worrying whether the function is defined at $C$ but that was silly. For $x<C$, we can just set the function to be $0$. I think this works thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean continuous differentiable by saying smooth, then this will work:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0, & x\le C;\\ 
(x-C)^2, & x>C.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This is a good and natural example

Comment: This is not good since the second derivative is not continuous at 0.

Comment: No one knows what you meant by smooth. You'd better say $C^\infty$ instead.

Comment: I apologize. C-infinity is what I meant by smooth.

Answer (score 0):

e^((x-3)^(1/2))

I guess you mean something like this, but actually a function is not really smooth if is not continuous in any point of function domain.